# How to generate number with textbox by javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I have one textbox called main_textbox when user enter any number i call javascript

function on the onblur event of textbox and by this code

---

```
function generate_bale(){
    var bale=document.getElementById("number_of_bale").value;
    var boxes = "<p>";
    for (var i=0;i<`bale`;i++){

        boxes+="<input type='text' name='bale_numbers[]'><br><br>";
    }
        document.getElementById("bale_box").innerHTML = boxes;
}
```

I genereate number of textbox which enter in main_textbox
now suppose if i want to generate number like 
1.textbox
2.textbox
3.textbox
so how to print this number in front textbox so i can identify from all generated textbox which number of textbox is
THANX in advance

Answer (score 1):

Did you ment to something like that?

```
function generate_bale(){
    var bale=document.getElementById("number_of_bale").value;
    var boxes = "<p>";
    for (var i=0;i<bale;i++){

        boxes+="<label for='bale_"+i+"'>"+i+"</label><input id='bale_"+i+"' type='text' name='bale_numbers[]'/><br/><br/>";
    }
    boxes+="</p>";
    document.getElementById("bale_box").innerHTML = boxes;
}
```

Comment: no no i dont need to enter number in name of textbox
but display like 1 textbox 
at view it display like 
1 textbox
2 textbox



 boxes+="i.<input type='text' name='balue_"+i+"'><br/><br/>";

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i=0;i<bale;i++){

    boxes+= i + ". <input type='text' name='bale_numbers[]'><br><br>";
}
    document.getElementById("bale_box").innerHTML = boxes;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may change the code that used to generate textbox as following:

```
boxes+="<label>"+ i + "<label><input type='text' name='bale_numbers[]'><br><br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function generate_bale(){

    var bale=document.getElementById("number_of_bale").value;
    var boxes = "<p>";

    for (var i=0;i<`bale`;i++){
        boxes+=+i+1+".textbox <input type='text' name='bale_numbers[]'><br><br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("bale_box").innerHTML = boxes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the following is the answer you expected,
[image]

Try this

```
function generate_bale(bale){
    var bale=document.getElementById("number_of_bale").value;
    var boxes = "<p>";
    for (var i=0;i<bale;i++){
        textboxNo = i+1;
        boxes+=textboxNo+".textbox<input type='text' name='balue_"+textboxNo+"'><br><br>";
    }
        document.getElementById("bale_box").innerHTML = boxes;
}
```

Check the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GAMme/)